# Ajax response processing interrupted when nesting another Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using Ajax requests via Jquery to update some parts of a web page.

Depending on the data values retrieved from the first Ajax request I send (or not) another nested Ajax request to get some more information.
Meaning the second Ajax request is nested in the first Ajax response handler.

Basically:

```
// Get some information
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: get_some_info_url})
  .done(
    function(msg)
    {
      // Given the info contained in msg, let send another request to get more
      if(msg.some_info === true)
      { 
        $.ajax({type: "POST", url: get_some_more_info_url})
           .done(
                function(msg2)
                {
                    // Do something
                }); 
      }

      // Display "Hello world!" whatever the msg.some_info value is.
      $('div#message-id').html("Hello world!");

    });
```

Different scenarios:

1. If msg.some_info is TRUE => **no displaying** of "Hello world!"
2. If msg.some_info is FALSE => **displaying** of "Hello world!"
3. More strange: If I set a breakpoint in the Firefox debugger on the line containing the second nested Ajax call (just stepping over the $.ajax call in the debugger) and msg.some_info is TRUE  => **displaying** of "Hello world!"

I'm a little confused here. Why does my second Ajax call prevent the rest of the code of the first Ajax response from being executed?
Is there some "race condition" or session management stuff?

And why breaking in the code "resolves" the issue?

**EDIT**: ISSUE RESOLVED. See my answer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Only possible reason is a JS error in your nested ajax call halting the JS engine from running further.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you might want to use the [Promise](http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/jquery/using-the-jquery-promise-interface-to-avoid-the-ajax-pyramid-of-doom/) stuff in jQuery to keep your code clean.

Comment: Have you defined `TRUE` somewhere? There is no `TRUE` in javascript syntax, boolean values are `true` and `false`. Try writing simply `if(msg.some_info)`. To understand read about truthy and falsy expressions in js

Comment: nested ajax calls work fine, you must have an error

Comment: What does `typeof msg.some_info` give you? if `type` is `boolean` then `===` makes sense, otherwise simply do as @KirillSlatin said above. And `true` and NOT `TRUE`

Comment: There are few syntax problems, TRUE is not correct keyword, === is not correct fit. Apart from this, by default jquery's ajax is ASYNC ..so check whether its printing "Hello World" even before nested ajax call finish.

Comment: RaviH: nop, there is no error. When I debug the code, everything goes fine.
bzlm: thanks, I will look into this.
Kirill, @LShetty: I will correct. This is some pseudo code to explain my problem. You are right TRUE is not defined. I'm not using it in my real code.
T McKeown: Certainly but why is it working when debugging is the key...

Comment: I think the most efficient would be to put this into fiddle

Comment: _If I set a breakpoint in the Firefox debugger on the line containing the second nested Ajax call (just stepping over the $.ajax call in the debugger) and msg.some_info is TRUE => displaying of "Hello world!"_

Are you sending your AJAX request after "dom ready"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should test for truth with === operator.

According to your comments,

```
// Given the info contained in msg, let send another request to get more
```

you just want to check if

```
msg.some_info
```

exists at all. In this case it's better to check by writing

```
if(msg.some_info) {
    /* Your code here*/
}
```

Another variant why msg.some_info is true but the "Hello world" isn't displayed is that your code hasn't response from the server and waits for it. Because you wrote "just stepping over the $.ajax call in the debugger) and msg.some_info is TRUE => displaying of "Hello world!"". So you step over that "bad point" and the message is diplayed than. That makes me think that there're some problems either in the code itself or in the server response which is not got back.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the issue. I'm going to write an answer. It was my mistake. I'll explain. For information I'm not testing boolean === true usually but did it here for making the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was on my side, sorry for wasting your time.

Actually I was erasing the "hello world!" text in the second Ajax response processing. Hence the difference between debugging run and normal run. The sequence for handling ajax responses was not the same with and without debugging hence misleading me about the root cause of the issue.

Thank you all for your help.